# can't get cookie using lua-resty-cookie

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm trying to use lua-resty-cookie in openresty project.
I'm having difficulty to get cookie key  using lua-resty-cookie way in one request.

nginx.conf:

```
...
/testcookie {

local ck = require "cookie"
local mycookie, err = ck:new()
if not mycookie then
  ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
  return ngx.say("assign failed: ",err)
end

local ok, err = mycookie:set({ key = "ckey", 
      value = "cvalue" })

if not ok then
  ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
  return ngx.say("set failed: ",err)
end

local field, err = mycookie:get('ckey')
if not field then
  ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
  return ngx.say("get failed: ",err)
end

return ngx.say('ckey: ',field)
}

...
```

What I got is "get failed: no cookie found in the current request\x{0a}"

Am I doing this wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

set() method of lua-resty-cookie set cookie to be sent in response to current request (Set-Cookie header).

get() method is used to extract cookies from current request (Cookie header).

So, you set cookie within response and later trying to find it in request ;-)